# Access Form suddenly stopped executing VBA code (solution) (Access365, Windows 10)

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events

This is not a question, actually it is how I fixed it.

I have an Access Form that is my start up and, of course, opens automatically. I have 1 button that runs VBA code, and suddenly, it stopped working, as well as the VBA code in OnFormLoad event. The buttons with MACRO code, though, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I went to Design View, added a new button with the VBA code in OnClick event: msgbox "Works" (can be anything). Once clicked on the button, the code executed normally and, "magically", button and OnLoad script started working again. I have no reasonable explanation for that...